# Why is PLINQ slower?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PLINQ Performs Worse Than Usual LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354518/plinq-performs-worse-than-usual-linq)

Does anyone know why this PLINQ code is slower than regular LINQ? Is there anyway to fix it?

```
// dic is a Dictionary<int, int>
var location = (from locations in dic.AsParallel
                             orderby locations.Value descending
                             select locations.Key).First();
return location;
```

Adding the ParallelQuery slows things down a lot by why would that be the case?

Comment: Parallelization isn't free. How many pairs are in the dictionary?

Comment: See: [PLINQ Performs Worse Than Usual LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354518/plinq-performs-worse-than-usual-linq)

Comment: @user385048: Read the analogy about brick laying vs wall building in Anthony's link.